# How to build native app in javascript on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, html, reactjs, native

How to build app in js which one you can run on Windows/Linux/Mac ?

Something smillar to https://discordapp.com/.

I saw some libraries like app.js ( last update 4 years ago), WinJs.

Is there something with React.js ? (Or i can just use React as view?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try http://electron.atom.io/ which based on node.js..
Atom editor was made with it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at http://nwjs.io/

Comment: What's biggest diffrence beetwen this and Electron?

Comment: Take a look here [link](https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/02/09/nw-js-vs-electron/)